# Convert a string of coordinates to a readable polyline for export as GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, convert, coordinates, excel

I need to take an xls file which has multiple columns of data, and a column called coordinates which is a string of coordinates (ex. 147.775364306,-20.49918551,0 147.776402476,-20.500021717,0 147.778202959,-20.5015774579999,0), and convert it to a GeoJSON file.

How can I do this easily?

Comment: What tools do you have? Just Excel? Or some kind of geospatial tool like QGIS or spatialite?

Comment: I have ArcMap as well, but I'm trying to simplify the input as much as possible for a very technologically challenged partner organization. So for them to be able to just fill in a spread sheet and send it to me, and then I can break down the coordinates and convert the format.

Answer (score 3):

Your coordinates look as though they are in the format x,y,z and are space separated. This is already pretty close to GeoJSON format. Presuming your Excel sheet looks like this:

```
      A       B       C                             D       
    |-------|-------|-----------------------------|---------|
  1 | data1 | data2 | coordinates                 | geoJson |
    |-------|-------|-----------------------------|---------|
  2 | foo   | bar   | x1,y1,z1 x2,y2,z2, x3,y3,z3 |         |  
    |-------|-------|-----------------------------|---------|
  3 | other | line  | xa,ya,za xb,yb,zb, xc,yc,zc |         |  
    |-------|-------|-----------------------------|---------|
```

You could easily use the following Excel function to create a column of GeoJSON compatible points under the "geoJSON" heading above (cell D2):

```
=CONCATENATE("{ 'type':'LineString','coordinates':[[",SUBSTITUTE(C2, " ", "],["), "]]}")
```

This will give you the result

```
{ 'type':'LineString','coordinates':[[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],[x3,y3,z3]]}
```

For each of your rows you will have the GeoJSON representation of the LineString, which you can then save as a file as you please. Please comment if this is not what you are looking for and I will adjust my answer!